# How to list all AppSettings keys in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, web.config-transform

I needed to list all AppSetting keys in a configuration page from the Web.Config.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the VB.Net Code behind.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim appSettings As NameValueCollection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim DR As DataRow
        Dim AppKey = New DataColumn("AppKey", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        Dim AppValue = New DataColumn("AppValue", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        DT.Columns.Add(AppKey)
        DT.Columns.Add(AppValue)
        For Each Key In appSettings.AllKeys
            DR = DT.NewRow()
            DR("AppKey") = Key
            DR("AppValue") = appSettings.Item(Key)
            DT.Rows.Add(DR)
        Next
        Dim DS As New DataSet()
        DS.Tables.Add(DT)
        AppSettingKeys.DataSource = DS
        AppSettingKeys.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the Page:

```
    <table>
        <asp:Repeater ID="AppSettingKeys" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr><td class="table-left-class2"><%#Eval("AppKey")%></td><td><%#Eval("AppValue")%></td></tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
```